# Custom series values in jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I am creating a charting solution using the jqPlot plugin. The user will have the ability to define all the values they want to chart. I am having a problem with adding a custom series to the chart though. customSeries is a string of values separated by a comma

```
var seriesLabels = customSeries.split(",");

        for(var i = 0; i<seriesLabels.length; i++)
        {
            series=new Object();
            series.label = seriesLabels [i];                
            seriesArray.push(series);
        }
```

Then I try to plot the series like so using the object seriesArray

```
plot2 = $.jqplot('placeHolder', frequincySingleGroupArray, {
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                pointLabels: { show: true }
            },
            series:[                    
                    seriesArray     
            ],
            legend: {
              show: true,
              location: 'e',
              placement: 'outside'
            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: params.Intervals.split(","),
                    pad: 10
                },
                yaxis: {

                }
            }, seriesColors: LegendColors.split(","),               
        });         
    });
```

This does not work.
If I change the series to

```
series:[seriesArray[0],seriesArray[1]]
```

This will work but it is not dynamic like I need it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to remove the square brackets like so

```
series:seriesArray
```

and this worked